# send SPECS to mapFish service using POST method

Tags: geoserver, mapfish

I'm using mapFish print-servlet-1.1 and I generate the PDF from the default interface (index.html) from tomcat. 
The print service is a standalone service deploied on tomcat 7.

If the form method is GET, everything is wotking fine.
If I want to use POST (to send more SPECS) I get this result: 
Error while generating PDF:
Unknown method: /print.pdf

Answer (score 1):

To POST, you need to call `http://{print url}/pdf/create.json` and post the json content and you will receive the response like:

```
{
   getURL: "http://{print url}/pdf/6013561557039431559.pdf"
}
```

from the getURL you can download the PDF file.